# Routes request hanging

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problems with these routes

```
# Routes
# 
router.get "/calendars", (req, res, next) ->
  Calendar.find (err, calendar) ->
    return next(err)  if err
    res.json calendar
    return

  return

router.post "/calendars", (req, res, next) ->
  calendar = new Calendar(req.body)
  calendar.save (err, post) ->
    return next(err)  if err
    res.json post
    return

  return
```

When I send a request to either of the API endpoints, the server hangs and eventually I get a request timed out error

Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure `Calendar.find()` and `calendar.save()` are calling the callback?

Comment: no idea, i just started fiddling with node

Comment: Should be easy enough, run it in node-inspector, put breakpoints and see, or just `console.log` right before `return next(err)` and see if it gets there

Answer (score 0):

Edit: try now. I don't see any thing wrong here. After running the POST, look for "checkpoint" in console. Let me know if it still doesn't works. I would like to know how you are calling the API.
Make sure you have defined the Calendar model before calling it.

```
   mongoose = require("mongoose")
Calendar = mongoose.model("Calendar")
ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId

router.get "/calendars", (req, res) ->
  Calendar.find (err, calendar) ->
    res.send err  if err
    res.json calendar
    return

  return

router.post "/calendars", (req, res) ->
  console.log "checkpoint: " + JSON.stringify(req.body)
  calendar = new Calendar(
    day: req.body.day
    month: req.body.month
    year: req.body.year
  )
  calendar.save (err, post) ->
    res.send err  if err
    res.json post
    return

  return
```

Comment: I tried this, but i still doesnt work. I tried either accessing the endpoint through at HTTP request program (Paw) and jsut visiting ut through the browser